# installing coffee-script on ubuntu installs all the files correctly but command line doesn't work

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, coffeescript, npm

All,

I have recently switched my dev environment from windows7 to Ubuntu12 and everything has been running smoothly except coffee-script.  I have executed this exact sequence of commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs  
sudo apt-get install npm  
//checked that both are their latest versions  
npm -g install coffee-script
```

when I do this I see only the following lines

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script  
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script  
/usr/bin/coffee -> /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee  
/usr/bin/cake -> /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake  
coffee-script@1.4.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
```

which coffee and which cake point to /usr/bin/coffee|cake but the commands actually do nothing at all.

I am at a loss.

Please send help!

Steve Kane

Comment: What if you `/usr/bin/coffee --help`?

Comment: m@muistooshort I see nothing.  I have also confirmed that actually navigating to my /usr/bin and calling coffee and cake does nothing.  It doesn't seem to be an issue of the commands not being on my PATH.  It seems more like coffee-script isn't getting installed...but the kicker is that the node_modules/coffee-script folder contains all the files you would expect to be here.

Comment: Have you checked the symlinks (both ends)? Have you inspected the contents of `/usr/bin/coffee` to see what it really is? Have you tried running `/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee --help`?

Comment: Yes sir.  I have checked out all of the above.  coffee and cake are just executables I believe (not sure this is proper linux vernacular).  They are installed globally per the recommendation of the NPM docs so that they are available as console commands.  They just seem to actually do nothing.  I am starting to wonder if it's not actually installing the needed files but just creating the links in the appropriate bin locations.  I only say this because, when installing socket.io, it actually pulls down tarballs and other files and takes several seconds to complete.

Comment: I could really use some help here as I'm at a total loss.  I have also tried cloning the master branch of Coffee Script from github and then using sudo bin/cake install but it does absolutely nothing at all.  I am truly clueless as to how to resolve this issue and all my googlefu has failed me thus far.

Comment: What is inside `/usr/bin/coffee` when you view it with `less`? What happens if you write a simple `class C` CoffeeScript file and `coffee -c` it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All,

I was not able to resolve this issue and wound up manually installing an older version of node by building it and not using sudo.  I think did the same for coffee-script.  It is now working correctly though I'm not entirely sure where the problem came from.

Answer (score 5):

Did have the same problem.
Uninstalling the package "node" (note: not nodejs but sic! "node") did it for me

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related to a package name conflict. See https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/936

Until this is fixed, you can manually link `/usr/bin/nodejs` to `/usr/bin/node`.

Answer (score 0):

Install [node.js](http://nodejs.org) using [Chris Lea's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Install [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install coffeescript
```

Now you can use `coffee` to build CoffeeScript, and `cake.coffeescript` to run Cake.

Comment: I've never been able to install coffeescript successfully using Chris' PPA. I'd recommend NVM.